# Multiple simultaneous requests with GWT addSubmitCompleteHandler

Tags: gwt

I'm doing multiple simultaneous fairly long running requests from one client however the addSubmitCompleteHandler only seems to trigger for the last one. Is this correct behavior?
I would like to update the ui based on the response of each form completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single form, then this is the expected behavior: each submission cancels the previous one.

You need to use one FormPanel per request.

Comment: Ok seems like it defeats the purpose of the ajax model but for form specific requests maybe it makes sense. I was using the same file selection field to upload multiple files but I guess I'll have to do it differently. Thanks